# Rendering at lower resolution with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, macos, performance, graphics, sprite-kit

I want to blur my background layer so I set the background SKNode to a child of SKEffectNode with a Gaussian blur filter attached.

Unfortunately it is very slow, cutting my FPS by 97%!

I'd like to render the background at lower resolution, and then upscale it. How can that be done with SpriteKit?

Comment: I tried shrinking the background node to 1/8th of its original size, then adding a parent node that has `xScale` and `yScale` set to 8.0. This gets back a measly half-frame per second. (This approach is what I used in the Processing version of my code and it is very smooth.)

Comment: Was it in MacOS or iOS? If iOS was it in the simulator or on the device?

Comment: I can provide you a really good answer, I just need to know the scenario.  Do you want just the background at a low resolution, or the entire scene